# How to use maxWidth in a LayoutBuilder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, constraints, flutter-layoutbuilder

```dart
 LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Container(
        width: constraints.maxWidth =
            0.5, //this is where maxWidth is being is used and it is just giving an error

        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: kPrimaryGradient,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use containers with constrains to achieve this layout. For example.

```
 constrains: BoxConstraints (
       maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutBuilder`'s constraints controlled by its parent widget. If you like to have 50% width of the constraints use

```
width: constraints.maxWidth *.5
```

The operation will `*` instead of `=`.

You can find more about [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)